# Visual Studio mvc update multiple data by one click

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am using Visual Studio with the ASP.NET MVC framework.

I have data in SQL, I want to bring it to Visual Studio in a table with checkbox buttons, then when the user checks the button such as "update" I want to update multiple columns in the data such as "year", "semester"...etc ،

I want data to be changed in the code, not by the user.

Comment: Hello, StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please produce an attempt at your issue before you ask others to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] - see [ask].